# CLLocation course property is not updating and always with -1 value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am developing an application where we should be tracking a vehicle. However, the course property in CLLocation always has a -1 value, although longitude and latitude are correct.

My desired accuracy is kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation

Any advice?!

Comment: Are you testing on a device with a compass?  According to the docs "Course values may not be available on all devices. A negative value indicates that the direction is invalid."

Comment: I actually don't have a compass app on my device if this is what you mean..

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing on iPhone 5 & 6

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find the answer?